# eslint vue-cli doesn't show errors after running npm run serve second time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, vue-cli-4

I am using These packages.

```
"@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
```

Running script -

```
"serve": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js serve --open",
```

My `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
}
```

When opening project and running  `npm run serve` , eslint shows errors. Then I quit the server by pressing ctrl + c and running `npm run serve` again and after that, eslint NEVER shows any errors in the console when I know that there're plenty of them.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Hey Nika! Would you be able to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi John , I don't think so . It's really gonna take some time.  It's not possible to figure out by looking at what I posted ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't see any configuration there that would autofix lint errors on serve.